# Prolog - Print truth table for first order table

Tags: prolog, evaluation

I've some difficults to print a truth table for first order logic.

The tasks is:

Write a Prolog predicate table (F, U) that receives one as input
well-formed formula in propositional logic F e
is satisfied by the rows of the truth table of formula F
which have U value. Formula F is expressed by
the function symbols not / 1, and / 2 and or / 2,
the constants t (for true) and f (for false),
any round brackets and use free variables as symbols
of proposition.

Example 
?- table(and(P, or(Q, P)), U)

P=t, Q=f, U=t; 
P=t, Q=t, U=t;
P=f, Q=f, U=f;
P=f, Q=t, U=f;

Comment: This is an easy peasy task in Prolog, please show us what you have tried...

Comment: Better represent a propositional variable as `atom(P)` otherwise you'll derive also `P = and(t,t)` etc. (using P directly is called a [defaulty](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/data) representation).